# List queued tasks with ActiveJob AsyncAdapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

Is there a way I can see how many (maybe even inspect each job?) jobs are there remaining in the queue?

Comment: hey, let me know whether below suggestion worked for you if you already tried it - I'm kind'a curious but not yet had a moment to test it :) (may be during weekend)

Comment: Same here :) Couldn't test it today. Let me see if I can get to that tomorrow morning ;)

Answer (score 7):

After some digging into [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb) here is what I found out:

[`ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/AsyncAdapter.html) uses a [Concurrent Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) thread pool to schedule and execute jobs.

When you initialize the adapter in your configuration, you pass ***executor options***, which in turn happen to be arguments to `initialize` method of
[`Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class.

Created instance of [`Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class has such methods, as:

- [`queue_length`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#queue_length-instance_method) -      The number of tasks in the queue awaiting execution.
- [`scheduled_task_count`](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduled_task_count-instance_method) - The number of tasks that have been scheduled for execution on the pool since construction.

That said, I think something along these lines should do it for you:

```
ActiveJob::Base
  .queue_adapter
  .instance_variable_get(:@scheduler)
  .instance_variable_get(:@async_executor)
  .public_send(:queue_length)
```

Above does the following:

1. get your adapter
2. get its instance_variable [`@scheduler`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb#L34), that points to
3. instance of `Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor` (instance variable of `Scheduler` class - [`@async_executor`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb#L87))
4. on which you can actually call the methods, described above (`queue_length`, `scheduled_task_count` and [others](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html))

Though I did not test it, so make sure to double check for typos or whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, I just tried. It doesn't seem to work. It returns 0 always.

Comment: @alexandernst think of it, it returns an integer, thus I'm pretty sure it is working in a sense, that it calls the correct method. Did you try another methods? Also, are you 1000% sure, it shouldn't return 0?

Comment: I tried this solution. I tried `queue_length`, `scheduled_task_count`, `completed_task_count`. All of them always return `0`

Comment: Getting the async_executor of the adapter is returning a Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor instance. The problem is that 
 Concurrent::ThreadPoolExecutor counts aren't updated for some reason.