# List of scheduled Active Job in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

How i can see the list scheduled or pending active job in rails 5.2.

I have Scheduled a job after 10min to send a email but user resend it again and again so i need to see that is job scheduled is executed or not.

My Job look like this
    class GenerateTemplatePreviewJob < ApplicationJob
      queue_as :default

```
  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

I Have Called The job from Model

```
 after_save ->{
   GenerateTemplatePreviewJob.set(wait_until: 
    10.second.after).perform_later(self.template.id.to_s) 
 }
```

Comment: If you're using sidekiq or delayed job it shuld be quite easy, delayed job looks quite a lot harder though....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032266/list-queued-tasks-with-activejob-asyncadapter looks like your best bet, genuinely surprised they make it that difficult

Comment: Not i am not using sidekiq

Comment: The link I provided works without either sidekiq or delayed job